# multiplying a variable without rewriting it

Tags: c#

So I am fairly new to the "code world" and hopefully have a fairly simply question.

```
txtBox.Text = "x";
```

How would I make it so I am able to see 10 X's in my `txtBox` without completely writing it out?

Comment: You should read about loops.

Comment: no need for loops @ray

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`string` has a constructor that repeats a character for a given number of times:

```
txtBox.Text = new string('x', 10);
```

It's documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx).

If what you want to repeat is a string (not a single character) you need a loop, but use a `StringBuilder` to minimise memory fragmentation. Try avoiding repetitive string concatenations:

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    stringBuilder.Append("ThePatternToRepeat");

txtBox.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

string has a constructor for this :-

```
txtBox.Text = new string('x',10);
```

alternatives are

looping:

```
  string s = "";
    for (var n = 0; n < 10; n++) s += "x";
    txtBox.Text = s;
```

Linq:

```
txtBox.Text =  Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Aggregate("", (a, n) => a + "x");
```

Comment: yeah, typo, fixed